# Android app runs perfectly in emulator but not on device due to external DB

Tags: java, android

I found out that the external database I use cannot access by querying in activity (DataConn.java).

the main menu of the app `MainActivity.java` is the one showed but when I press the button with the effect of redirecting to another layout activity `ingameinterface.java`, it crashes. T^T
how may I fix this? please help!

DataConn.java

```
package com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.Random;


public class DataConn extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_vocabulary.db";
    private static final String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.exampasle.hamira.wordmatchinggame/databases/";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tblwords";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    static int taksi, pamato, a;


    public DataConn(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public Cursor getAllData(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int patad = r.nextInt(41 - 0) + 1;
        pamato = patad;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select " +
                "max(case when Key_Word = 'Questn' then Val end) Question,\n" +
                "max(case when Key_Word = 'Defi' then Val end) Definition,\n" +
                "max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc1' then Val end) Choice1,\n" +
                "max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc2' then Val end) Choice2,\n" +
                "max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc3' then Val end) Choice3,\n" +
                "max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc4' then Val end) Choice4,\n" +
                "max(case when Key_Word = 'Ans' then Val end) Answer,\n" +
                "max(case when Key_Word = 'Stats' then Val end) Status\n" +
                "from "+TABLE_NAME+" where prima = '"+pamato+"'", null);

        res.close();
        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getScore(){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor sc = db.rawQuery("select crntscore from TblScore",null);
        return sc;
    }

    public Cursor UpdateScore(){
        taksi=ingameinterface.passScore;
        a = taksi+1;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor us = db.rawQuery("update TblScore set crntscore='"+a+"'",null);
        us.moveToFirst();
        us.close();
        return us;
    }
    public Cursor DropPrima(){

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor udp = db.rawQuery("update TblWords set Val = '1' where CtrlNo = '8' " +
                "and Prima ='"+pamato+"'",null);
        udp.moveToFirst();
        udp.close();

        return udp;
    }
    public Cursor ResetPrima(){
        int a = ingameinterface.passPrima;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor udp = db.rawQuery("update TblWords set Val = '0' where CtrlNo = '8' " +
                "and Prima ='"+a+"'",null);
        udp.moveToFirst();
        udp.close();

        return udp;
    }
    public Cursor ResetScore(){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor us = db.rawQuery("update TblScore set crntscore='0'",null);
        us.moveToFirst();
        us.close();
        return us;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent game;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        game = new Intent( MainActivity.this, ingameinterface.class);

        TextView btnstrt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame);
        btnstrt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                startActivity(game);

            }

        });

        final View btnoff = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnVoloff);
        final View btnon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnVolon);

        btnon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == btnon) {
                    btnoff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //TURN OFF AUDIO

                }
            }
        });
        btnoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == btnoff) {
                    btnoff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //TURN ON AUDIO

                }
            }
        });


        TextView btnexit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnQuit);
        btnexit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

ingameinterface.java

```
package com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class ingameinterface extends Activity {
    DataConn myDb;
    String  holdQstn, holdDefi, holdCc1, holdCc2, holdCc3, holdCc4,holdAns, holdStats;
    static int DBscore, passScore;
    static int patad, passPrima;
    TextView TVScore;
    TextView TVWord, TVDefi, TVCc1, TVCc2, TVCc3, TVCc4;
    Button ResetBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingameinterface);

        myDb = new DataConn(this);
        CharSequence text = "GAME ON !";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        rand();
         hereWeGo();
        ShowMyScore();


        //BUTTON CHOICE 1
        TVCc1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmCc1);
        TVCc1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String BtnText1 = TVCc1.getText().toString();
                if(holdAns.equals(BtnText1)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), BtnText1+" is the correct answer. " +
                            "Excellent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    performAddScore();
                    ShowMyScore();
                    dropPrima();
                    hereWeGo();
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hereWeGo();
                }
            }
        });
        //BUTTON CHOICE 2
        TVCc2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmCc2);
        TVCc2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String BtnText2 = TVCc2.getText().toString();
                if(holdAns.equals(BtnText2)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), BtnText2+" is the correct answer. " +
                            "Excellent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    performAddScore();
                    ShowMyScore();
                    dropPrima();
                    hereWeGo();
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hereWeGo();
                }
            }
        });
        //BUTTON CHOICE 3
        TVCc3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmCc3);
        TVCc3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String BtnText3 = TVCc3.getText().toString();
                if(holdAns.equals(BtnText3)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), BtnText3+" is the correct answer. " +
                            "Excellent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    performAddScore();
                    ShowMyScore();
                    dropPrima();
                    hereWeGo();
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hereWeGo();
                }
            }
        });
        //BUTTON CHOICE 4
        TVCc4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmCc4);
        TVCc4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String BtnText4 = TVCc4.getText().toString();
                if(holdAns.equals(BtnText4)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), BtnText4+" is the correct answer. " +
                            "Excellent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    performAddScore();
                    ShowMyScore();
                    dropPrima();
                    hereWeGo();
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hereWeGo();
                }
            }
        });

        ResetBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
        ResetBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(ingameinterface.this);
                build.setTitle("Reset Confirmation");
                build.setMessage("Do you want to reset the game?");
                build.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //BUTTON YES
                        for(int a=1; a!=41; a++){
                            passPrima = a;
                            myDb.ResetPrima();
                        }
                        myDb.ResetScore();
                        hereWeGo();
                        ShowMyScore();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game reset successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                build.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //BUTTON NO
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog wew = build.create();
                wew.show();

            }
        });


    }//onCreate END
public void rand(){
    Random r = new Random();
    patad = r.nextInt(41 - 0) + 1;
}

    public  void hereWeGo(){

        Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
        if(res.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        while (res.moveToNext()){
            holdQstn = String.valueOf(res.getString(0));
            holdDefi = String.valueOf(res.getString(1));
            holdCc1 = String.valueOf(res.getString(2));
            holdCc2 = String.valueOf(res.getString(3));
            holdCc3 = String.valueOf(res.getString(4));
            holdCc4 = String.valueOf(res.getString(5));
            holdAns = String.valueOf(res.getString(6));
            holdStats = String.valueOf(res.getString(7));
            if (holdStats.equals("1")){
                reRollCall();
            }else{
                TVWord= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmWORD);
                String StrngToTVQstn = holdQstn;
                TVWord.setText("'"+StrngToTVQstn+"'");
                TVDefi= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmDefi);
                String StrngToTVDefi = holdDefi;
                TVDefi.setText(StrngToTVDefi);
                TVCc1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmCc1);
                String StrngToTVCc1 = holdCc1;
                TVCc1.setText(StrngToTVCc1);
                TVCc2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmCc2);
                String StrngToTVCc2 = holdCc2;
                TVCc2.setText(StrngToTVCc2);
                TVCc3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmCc3);
                String StrngToTVCc3 = holdCc3;
                TVCc3.setText(StrngToTVCc3);
                TVCc4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmCc4);
                String StrngToTVCc4 = holdCc4;
                TVCc4.setText(StrngToTVCc4);
            }
        }

    }
    public void reRollCall(){
        hereWeGo();
    }

    public void performAddScore(){
        Random r = new Random();
        patad = r.nextInt(41 - 0) + 1;
        myDb.UpdateScore();

    }
    public void ShowMyScore(){
        Cursor sc = myDb.getScore();
        while (sc.moveToNext()){
            DBscore= Integer.valueOf(sc.getInt(0));
            passScore = DBscore;
            TVScore= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmSCORE);
            TVScore.setText(String.valueOf(passScore));

        }
    }
    public void dropPrima(){
        myDb.DropPrima();

    }
}//class END
```

**EDIT:** sorry! wrong logcat pasted.

UPDATED logcat

```
    08-02 11:56:54.418 17223-17223/com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: tblwords 08-02 11:56:54.419 17223-17223/com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 08-02 11:56:54.420 17223-17223/com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame, PID: 17223
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame/com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame.ingameinterface}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblwords (code 1): , while compiling: select max(case when Key_Word = 'Questn' then Val end) Question,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Defi' then Val end) Definition,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc1' then Val end) Choice1,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc2' then Val end) Choice2,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc3' then Val end) Choice3,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc4' then Val end) Choice4,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Ans' then Val end) Answer,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Stats' then Val end) Status
from tblwords where prima = '8'
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2525)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2617)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5657)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:990)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:785)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblwords (code 1): , while compiling: select max(case when Key_Word = 'Questn' then Val end) Question,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Defi' then Val end) Definition,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc1' then Val end) Choice1,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc2' then Val end) Choice2,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc3' then Val end) Choice3,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Cc4' then Val end) Choice4,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Ans' then Val end) Answer,
max(case when Key_Word = 'Stats' then Val end) Status
from tblwords where prima = '8'
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1346)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1285)
    at com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame.DataConn.getAllData(DataConn.java:38)
    at com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame.ingameinterface.hereWeGo(ingameinterface.java:167)
    at com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame.ingameinterface.onCreate(ingameinterface.java:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
        ... 10 more 08-02 11:56:54.474 17223-17223/com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17223 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "external database" because you seem to only be using a local Sqlite database

Answer (score 0):

in emulator , you pushed the database in path /data/data . That is the reason it is working in emulator.

But in real device, you have not pushed the database to this path.That's why crash says "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table".

PS: /data/data , is a secured path.If you want to move database to this path. you need to write some more code.

Comment: can you help me do that please :(

Comment: @user5425674, if the external database is empty,go on and create the tables. If the external database contains some data. The solution will be depend on how you want to ship the initial database !

Answer (score 0):

in `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` you have to execute script to create database table(s) ex,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (field1 VARCHAR,field2 VARCHAR);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (field1 VARCHAR,field2 VARCHAR);");
    //... etc
}
```

now after you add the correct create-table script, uninstall app from device and run the project again. it should create the tables and it will work fine.

you need to read more about sqlite helper class and how it works.